# Add and delete buttons in django jquery dynamic formset

Tags: django

I use https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset to add and delete rows from a formset.

The problem is that the `add row` and `delete row` buttons are automatically inserted weird places.

Can I place these buttons manually?

Or are there any other jquery libraries to add and delete rows in a formset dynamically?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can place these buttons manually, maybe if you check the rules followed by the plugin to place the buttons: https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset/blob/master/src/jquery.formset.js#L49

As you can see:

//If the forms are laid out in table rows, insert
// the remove button into the last table cell

// If they're laid out as an ordered/unordered list,
// insert an < li > after the last list item

// Otherwise, just insert the remove button as the
// last child element of the form's container

You can specify addCssClass (which is by default 'add-row'), maybe that can help you.